# How to registerMetaTag and replace content after content renders?

Tags: yii, meta-tags

I use a layout with metatags;

```
<meta name="description" id="meta_description" content="content here" />
<meta name="keywords" id="meta_keywords" content="job" />

<meta property="og:title" id="meta_og_title" content="og title"/>
<meta property="og:image" id="meta_og_image" content="og image"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" id="meta_og_site_name" content="og site name"/>
<meta property="og:description" id="meta_og_description" content="og description" />
```

I generate the content;

Within that content i register some meta tags:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag('Job search', 'description', null, array('id'=>'meta_description'), 'meta_description');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag('Job search', 'keywords', null, array('id'=>'keywords'), 'meta_keywords');

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag('mogt', '', null, array('id'=>'meta_og_title', 'property' => 'og:title'), 'meta_og_title');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag('mogi', '', null, array('id'=>'meta_og_image', 'property' => 'og:image'), 'meta_og_image');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag('mogsn', '', null, array('id'=>'meta_og_site_name', 'property' => 'og:site_name'), 'meta_og_site_name');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag('mogd', '', null, array('id'=>'meta_og_description', 'property' => 'og:description'), 'meta_og_description');
```

Why does yii register the meta tags, before inserting the static meta tags?

I want to modify the static tags, i dont want to duplicate the meta tags;

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What "static" meta tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation:

> **Note:** Each call of this method will cause a rendering of new meta tag, even if their attributes are equal.

if you want to overwrite existing tag make sure you have added the first one with `registerMetaTag`
so that the 5th parameter `$id` is same

Comment: <meta name="description" id="meta_description" content="content here" /> and Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag('Job search', 'description', null, array('id'=>'meta_description'), 'meta_description'); looks the same to me

Comment: Don't add statically, let yii render it all. Yii is not keeping track of HTML you are entering yourself.